# Jekyll Kramdown preserve new lines

Tags: html, markdown, jekyll, liquid, kramdown

I need to find a way to make **Kramdown** preserve new lines in jekyll posts which are writen in markdown

for example this text:

```
Hello
darkness
my
old
firend
```

is ouputed as:

```html
<p>Hellodarknessmyoldfriend</p>
```

and I want it to be:

```html
<p>Hello<br/>darkness<br/>my<br/>old<br/>friend</p>
```

How to config kramdown to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Markdown a linebreak is added with a backslash (\) at the end of the line in question.

```
Hello\
darkness\
my\
old\
friend
```

Output:

```html
<p>Hello<br/>darkness<br/>my<br/>old<br/>friend</p>
```

Per the [official Kramdown docs](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#paragraphs), you need two backslashes, but I tested this in one of my projects and it works as listed above.

If you're *not* trimming whitespace, you could use two spaces at the end of the line, but that's still something extra you'd need to add.

If you are looking for a way to add nothing at the end and have a line-return create a `<br>` tag, there is no way to do this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunetly this does not work in my case. Jekyll's kramdown is taking it as character and not as breakline.

Comment: Are you sure you are using Kramdown? I tested this with Kramdown in one of my projects and it works as listed above. According to the official docs, you need two backslashes: https://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#paragraphs

Comment: `\\` works as intended. But I was looking for solution without making any editing to text it self. Some global settings which control behavior of renderer. Maybe I question was not  clear enough. I will edit it. 

This answer still deserves upvote.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to add nothing to the end of the line and have markdown do something different. If you're not trimming whitespace, you could use two spaces at the end, but that's still something extra you'd need to add.

Comment: Okey, than add this information to the answer (more details with sources) and I will accept it as solution.